# Ordinary differential equations Matlab and finding a value using Heun's method

Tags: matlab, ode

How can I solve the following ODE: f'' + t*f' + 3*f = sin(3*t) 
with the initial conditions at t=0, f=2, and df/dt=1, and plot the solution from t =0 to 5 using (Dt)=0.1 spacing. Also solving for the value f(5) using Heun's method.

Here is what I have tried below

```
time=(0:0.01:5);
Sol=[0];
f=[2];
df=[1];
for(mm=1:length(time)-1);
   f(mm+1)=df(mm)*.01+f(mm);
   df(mm+1)=(f(mm+1)-f(mm))/0.01;
end
ww=(1);  
for(kk=0:0.01:5-0.02);   
V=(f(ww+2)-2*f(ww+1)+f(ww))/(0.01)^2+kk*((f(ww+2)-f(ww+1))/0.01)+f(ww+1);
    Sol=[Sol V];
    ww=ww+1;
end
Sol=[Sol 0];
figure(5)
plot(time,Sol);
```

Comment: I'd change it into a system of first order ODEs of the form $g' = F(t,g)$ then solve that with Huen's method.
There are a few answers for solving second order ODEs with MATLAB.

Comment: It's Heun's method, spoken like Hoin. The explicit variant of the midpoint method.

Comment: @LutzL Wikipedia gives it as the improved Euler method, not explicit midpoint.

Comment: You are right, I mixed them up again. Heun is the explicit trapezoidal method.

Answer (score 3):

Runge-Kutta methods, like Heun's method is one, are defined for first order differential equations or systems. Since your equation is second order, the first task is to transform it into a system of first order:
`f'' + t*f' + 3*f = sin(3*t)` gets transformed as
`y1(t) = f(t)`, `y2(t) = f'(t)` with derivatives 
`y1'(t) = y2(t)`, `y2'(t) = f''(t) = sin(3*t) - t*y2(t) - 3*y1(t)`.

```
function dy = odefunc(t,y)
    dy = [ y(2); sin(3*t) - t*y(2) - 3*y(1) ]
end function
```

Then you can perform the Heun method in an iteration with fixed step length as

```
t0 = 0
tf = 5
y0 = [1; 2]

N=50
Dt = (tf - t0)/N

y = y0
t=t0
Sol = [y0]
time = [t0]
for i = 1:N
    k1 = odefunc(t,y)
    k2 = odefunc(t+Dt, y+k1*Dt)
    y = y + 0.5*Dt*(k1+k2)
    t = t + Dt
    Sol = [Sol y]
    time = [time t]
end
```